# PHP Create Multi-dimensional list of values from array of filepath strings

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filepath, explode

I have an array of arrays containing filepaths

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => cat/file1.php
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => dog/file2.php
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => cow/file3.php
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => cow/file4.php
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => dog/bowl/file5.php
        )

)
```

and need to convert it into a single multi-dimensional array holding the file names based on those file paths i.e.

```
Array
(
    [cat] => Array
        (
            [0] => file1.php
        )

    [dog] => Array
        (
            [0] => file2.php
            [bowl] => Array
                (
                     [0] => file5.php
                )

        )
    [cow] => Array
        (
            [0] => file3.php
            [1] => file4.php
        )

)
```

I have been experimenting with exploding the string and using for/foreach loops to build up an array non-recursively/recursively but have been unsuccessful so far

Comment: Can provide your code you have tried so far, which does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it can be confusing when iterating through associative arrays, especially if there's folder structure encoded in array values. But without fear and using references, one can manage. Here's a working snippet:

```
$array = [
    ['cat/file1.php'],
    ['dog/file2.php'],
    ['cow/file3.php'],
    ['cow/file4.php'],
    ['dog/bowl/file5.php'],
    ['dog/bowl/file6.php'],
    ['dog/bowl/soup/tomato/file7.php']
];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $subArray)
{
    foreach ($subArray as $filePath)
    {
        $folders = explode('/', $filePath);
        $fileName = array_pop($folders); // The last part is always the filename

        $currentNode = &$result; // referencing by pointer
        foreach ($folders as $folder)
        {
            if (!isset($currentNode[$folder]))
                $currentNode[$folder] = [];

            $currentNode = &$currentNode[$folder]; // referencing by pointer
        }
        $currentNode[] = $fileName;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

The result is the following:

```
array(3) {
  'cat' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(9) "file1.php"
  }
  'dog' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(9) "file2.php"
    'bowl' =>
    array(3) {
      [0] =>
      string(9) "file5.php"
      [1] =>
      string(9) "file6.php"
      'soup' =>
      array(1) {
        'tomato' =>
        array(1) {
          [0] =>
          string(9) "file7.php"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  'cow' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(9) "file3.php"
    [1] =>
    string(9) "file4.php"
  }
}
```

...which, I guess, is what you wanted.

Comment: perfect, thanks! Did not think about using references